# Can't figure out the other focal length for this plano-convex lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

The original question:

> A plano-convex lens has a thickness of 4 cm. When placed on a horizontal table, with the curved surface in contact with it, the apparent depth of the bottom most point of the lens is found to be 3 cm. If the lens is inverted such that the the table, the apparent depth of the centre of the plane face of the lens is found to be 25/8 cm. Find the focal length of the lens.

My attempt:

I first considered the case where the convex part of the lens is in contact with the table. I assume there is a point sized object just inside the lens - right at the portion of the lens in direct contact with the table.

I was aware of this formula: $H_{apparent} = H_{real} * \frac { \mu_{observer}}{\mu_{object}} $

I took $H_{apparent}$ to be the distance of the image which was 3cm. However I'm unsure that whether this distance of 3cm is measured from the flat end of the lens or the convex end? I believe that the observer is looking from the flat side of the lens, and since we are dealing with apparent depth here, 3cm should be measured from the flat end.

From this I found out the refractive index ($\mu_{object}$) of the lens, which came out to be 4/3.

Okay. Now I applied the formula of spherical refracting surfaces for the second case (i.e the case where the flat surface of the lens is in direct contact with the table).[image: Second Case]

I extended the lens from the flat side of the lens. Clearly, distance of the object from the convex top of the lens is 4cm. Radius of curvature can be easily found, which comes out to be 25cm.

Then all I had to was apply lens maker's formula and get myself the focal length of the lens, equal to 75cm. However there is another focal length for this lens on the *other* side which is (according the the answer given) is equal to 72cm.

I can not figure out how to find the second focal length. In fact it doesn't make sense to me how one lens can have two focal lengths? This seems absurd.

Any tips / guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for putting in thee time and effort to explain the question and what you have tried!

Comment: perhaps, for practical reasons, the focal length is calculated from the table surface, not from the lens center, therefore , the lens being asymmetric, when it's flipped, the focal length changes. If we take the lens center to be 0.5cm from one side of the lens (therefore 3.5cm from the other side) when the lens is flipped you get a 3.5-0.5=3cm difference

Comment: @ManudeHanoi Well again, where did you pull that number, '0.5' from? I understand you used that number to support your argument.. but it this doesn't really help me to reach the answer 72cm - however it has given me more vision.